# Complex function question regarding the function with the form $F(z) = \alpha z + \beta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems

I am having trouble with this problem in my Dynamical System class.

> Prove that the complex function $F(z) = \alpha z + \beta$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex is conjugate to a linear function of the form $L_{\gamma} (z) = \gamma z$.  Determine $\gamma$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  What happens when $\alpha = 1$?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far? If $L_{\gamma}(z)$ is conjugate to $F(z)$, which equation(s) does that lead to?

Comment: Well I tried drawing out the two functions on the complex/real plane using different parameters.  When two functions are conjugate to each other their behaviours are similar.

Comment: Is this the **exact** problem? Note that $L_\gamma$ has a fixed point (usually only one).

Comment: Yes sir it is the exact problem .  Yeah I know that $L_{\gamma}$ had a fixed point at $z =0$

Comment: Now what about the fixed point(s) of F?

Comment: 1 also right? I think so at least.